# Is this sentence correct? 'Please contact with the mobile number given in this notice.'

Tags: prepositions

Is this sentence correct?

> Please contact *with* the mobile number given in this notice.

I am confused about the usage of preposition in this sentence.

Comment: Which preposition? *In* or *with*?

Comment: The preposition 'with'.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is clumsy. *Contact* needs an object such as *me/us/the office*.
And *with* is not the most suitable preposition. *At* is better.

Better alternatives might be:

> Please contact ME/US at the mobile number given in this notice.

Or depending on how much you might wish to shorten it:

> Please contact us at the mobile number *above/below*
>
> Please contact us at this number ......
>
> Please contact us at..........